# commons-io: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, apache-commons-io, gzipinputstream

I'm using the Apache library **commons-io** in verion *2.6* to parse a zip stream and get its bytes. But when I call `IOUtils.toByteArray(zipStreamObject)` I get a **java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream**.

Here's my code:

```
public static void descompactarArquivoZip(Path arquivoZip) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(arquivoZip.toFile());
    try(ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is)) {
        unzipStream(zis);
    }
}

private static void unzipStream(ZipInputStream zis) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(zis); // the error occurs here
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2314)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2291)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2246)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:765)
```

BTW, I know that I can just adopt this solution: [Exception: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531089/exception-unexpected-end-of-zlib-input-stream) but I don't want to implement this in my code and, actually, I have a **Non GZIP Stream** error when I tried to do this.

Can someone, please, help me?